# Few questions about NoSQL/MongDB

Tags: mongodb, nosql, ide

I am new to NoSQL/MongoDB. Can someone please help answer a few questions. It would be very helpful if you can please reply in the same format. Thank you

1. Do all NoSQL databases store data in a plan text format?
2. Do they all store in JSON format or does mongoDB only store in JSON format?
3. How do you query a NoSQL/MongoDB? What tool and what languge? Example, you query Oracle SQL database with TOAD/SQL developer using the SQL language. How would you query mongoDB and with what language? Which IDE do you use?
4. I know learning "R" is popular. Can I query mongoDB with R?

Comment: [Do all NoSQL databases store data in a plan text format?](https://www.quora.com/How-is-data-stored-in-NoSQL-databases-What-are-the-data-structures-used-in-order-to-increase-reading-writing-speed-e-g-is-there-anything-similar-to-B-Tree-in-relational-databases)

Comment: MongoDB has pretty good docs [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/)

Comment: thank you for your help.